# How to activate the cursor in VS2010 after pressing Ctrl-Tab?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

When you come from a tool window and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go back to an editor window, the cursor is gone and replaced with a "line cursor" that only allows to scroll up/down but not enter text. Is there a key I can press to get the normal cursor back?

(This is especially useful to quickly compile my code <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and then just type on after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> without having to click the mouse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. This brings you the editor you last typed in with the cursor at the latest position.